# Customized matplotlib style with matplotlibrc doesn't load

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, configuration

I customized my own matplotlib style with matplotibrc by using the commands:

```
plt.style.reload_library()
plt.style.available
```

I was able to retreive my cumstomized style. However, when trying to load it with the command:

```
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
matplotlib.rcParams["backend"] = "TkAgg"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('MyCustomedStyle')
```

It's not being loaded. As you see, I have also tried to change the backend to use TkAgg for an interactive session, since I want to have it printed out on the screen.
I'm not getting any error messages.  Still, however, it is not changing to my customized style.

I have also tried the command:

```
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
%matplotlib inline
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks correct. How did you verify that the style is not correctly applied? What exact steps would one need to perform to reproduce the undesired behaviour?

Comment: As a test I created a dummy file in python called dummy.mplstyle with the following content:
text.color          : 777777
axes.facecolor      : f7f7f5   # axes background color
backend             : TkAgg

Comment: in the directory where the matplotlib stylesheets are located.  However, I justed saw that it is stored as dummy.mplstyle.py which is probably the reasons why it's not able to retrieve it. 
It is probably a stupid question but how can I convert it to dummy.mplstyle? It keeps adding the ending .py when I'm trying to change it manually...

Comment: Yes, it needs to end with `.mplstyle`. You need to find out how you name a file correctly in the program and operating system you are using.

Comment: thank you. it worked perfectly now :-)